# Array join with commas, only when element is not nil

Tags: ruby, arrays, join

Is there a starightforward way to achieve `array.join(", ")` where the comma is only included between elements that exist? I.e., if some elements don't exist in the array, I don't end up getting orphan commas?

Comment: Exist? Do you mean other than `nil`, perchance? All elements of an array--including `nil`-- are objects, which exist at least in our minds. If it's `nil` you want to skip, it may be easiest to use [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) to remove them before you join: `arr.compact.join(',')`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If an element does not exist, then it does not exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Example:

`["", nil, "test word", 5, 7, nil, "", nil, "", 7, 6, ""] => "test word, 5, 7, 7, 6"`

*Edit: Please note that the first method here requires Ruby on Rails. Use the second method for a Ruby-only solution*

You can try this to remove both `nil` and empty strings `""` and then join with commas (It removes all `nil` values with `compact`, then it does `split` on `""` to create a two-dimensional array where any `""` elements in the first array are just empty arrays in the new 2D array, then it does `flatten` which turns the 2D array back into a normal array but with all the empty arrays removed, and finally it does the `join(", ")` on this array):

```
> array.compact.split("").flatten.join(", ")


array = ["", nil, "test word", 5, 7, nil, "", nil, "", 7, 6, ""]

array.compact => ["", "test word", 5, 7, "", "", 7, 6, ""].split("") => [[], ["test word", 5, 7], [], [7, 6], []].flatten => ["test word", 5, 7, 7, 6].join(", ") => "test word, 5, 7, 7, 6"
```

---

Edit: Another way would be:

```
> array.reject(&:blank?).join(", ")


array = ["", nil, "test word", 5, 7, nil, "", nil, "", 7, 6, ""]

array.reject(&:blank?) => ["test word", 5, 7, 7, 6].join(", ") => "test word, 5, 7, 7, 6"
```

Comment: Rails also has the `.blank?` method that helps in the second case.

Comment: `split` is not defined on Array. It may be in Rails, but OP didn't state they were using Rails. Nevertheless, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Your new edit with explanatory text helps. You may want to add that this is a Rails-specific answer.

Comment: the second could be more concise: `array.reject(&:blank?).join(", ")`

Comment: @MarkThomas good point I changed it to specify that first method requires Rails. For your suggestion about using the `&:blank?` OP wants to get rid of both `nil` values and `""` values, so that wouldn't be work in this case.

Comment: @sid To do it that way keep in mind that `blank?` is also present on `nil` values so there's no need for extra testing. Additionally, instead of that you can do `array.reject(&:blank?)` to keep your logic positive, or `array.select(&:present?)` which is the inverse test.

Comment: Second method is using `blank?` which is provided by Rails, thus it cannot be used in ruby-only.

Answer (score 10):

I think you have nil elements in your array. You can do this:

```
arr.compact.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to `compact` the array before `join`. It returns a copy of array without `nil` elements.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact

```
[1,nil,2,3].compact.join(', ')
```

You can also use `compact!` to remove the `nil` elements from the source array itself (without making a copy).

Answer (score 1):

This answer will join all array elements except nil from a nested array as well as a flat array:

```
[1, nil, 3, [:a, nil, :c], 5, nil, 7].flatten.compact.join(',')
=> "1,3,a,c,5,7"
```

nils are suppressed from the output and do not appear in the joined string, and there are no commas around missing (nil) elements.